# Proactive Conversations

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/UniversalBot/#starting-conversations

I've been successful at using this approach in the emulator environment, where the MS bot templates use the ChatConnector and a restify server to process incoming requests.

Can it also be used when deploying on the Azure Bot Service?  In that environment the bot templates generally have you using BotServiceConnector and there is no restify server.

I added one to listen on a specific port so that I could try and trigger the proactive beginDialog.  I'm getting literally no response.

Comment: Can you share your code for the server configuration that is causing the error?

Comment: Hey Matt, check out this sample: https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botFramework-proactiveMessages/blob/master/node/simpleSendMessage/index.js  It is a simple example of how to create a custom endpoint ( CustomWebApi ) in the bot that can be called to proactively send a message.

Comment: Yeah thanks Eric.  I actually patterned what I did off the Start New Dialog example.   Evidently my issue was deploying as a Bot Service vs. as a Web App.   Somehow missed the distinction when I was first learning.

Working on getting it deployed outside the Bot Service and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is Node.JS Bot Framework and not a Bot Service (these are different), you should try deploying to a new Azure Web Service using the Node template.  You can do a search for the Node template when creating it.

After that, the Web Service will listen on port 80 by design and respond appropriately.  The local settings are for debugging locally AFAIK.

Comment: Not sure I follow, I'm developing a bot in Node using the Framework emulator in the dev environment and then deploying as a Bot Service on Azure.  

I need to be able to initiate a bot dialog from the bot side (as opposed to the user side).  I'm not clear on how your approach will accomplish that.

Comment: Don't deploy to a Bot Service but to a standard Web Service.  To be clear:  Code in an Azure Bot Service is based on Azure Functions and is not the same as an app developed using Bot Framework.  You should deploy to an Azure Web Service created using the Node template.

Your post isn't clear about how you are initiating a chat, just that you're not getting responses from your bot deployed to a Bot Service.

Comment: The how was described in the link I provided, which apparently now is redirecting to something completely different.  Looks like things in the Azure environment and documentation are evolving quickly.  

Basically I was listening for a POST to a specific route and then using UniversalBot.beginDialog to initiate.  

I'll look into deploying as a Web Service.

Comment: Appreciate the response. I wasn't previously aware of the distinction between the Bot Service and a Bot Framework as a web service.  I'm following you now.  If it's not using the Bot Service then the bot wouldn't use the BotServiceConnector and it would always have a restify server, so listening for POSTs to a custom route shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I'm not going to post my code because it's proprietary - what is it you're interested in seeing/knowing?  Maybe I can provide a snippet.

Comment: @MattB. just trying to help you troubleshoot the issue.